# How do I compress a folder with the Python GZip module?

Tags: python, compression, gzip, tar

I'm creating Python software that compresses files/folders... How would I create a section of the code that asks for the user input of the folder location and then compresses it. I currently have the code for a single file but not a folder full of files. Please explain in detail how to do this.

Comment: Isn't gzip supposed to do only compression, not archiving? Shouldn't you be perhaps looking at tar instead?

Answer (score 29):

The code to compress a folder in to tar file is:

```
import tarfile

tar = tarfile.open("TarName.tar.gz", "w:gz")
tar.add("folder/location", arcname="TarName")
tar.close()
```

It works for me. Hope that works for you too.

Answer (score 11):

I don't do UI, so you're on your own for getting the folder name from the user. Here's one way to make a gz-compressed tarfile. It does *not* recurse over subfolders, you'll need something like os.walk() for that.

```
# assume the path to the folder to compress is in 'folder_path'

import tarfile
import os

with tarfile.open( folder_path + ".tgz", "w:gz" ) as tar:
    for name in os.listdir( folder_path ):
        tar.add(name)
```

Comment: Actually you can just write `tar.add(folder_path)` and it will be added recursively. (Of course, this could be a new feature added in the five years since this answer was posted!) Also, the for loop shouldn't be indented here, unless you change `tar = tarfile.open(...)` to `with tarfile.open(...) as tar:` (which is a good idea, and then you can get rid of the `tar.close()` line).

Comment: Thanks, not sure how that indent error survived for 5 years.

Comment: Don't you need to have `tar.add(os.path.join(folder_path, name))`?

Answer (score 8):

GZip doesn't do compression of folders/directories, only single files. Use the [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) module instead.

Answer (score 0):

As larsmans says, gzip compression is not used for directories, only single files. The usual way of doing things with linux is to put the directory in a tarball first and then compress it.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can get better compression when you tar and then compress than if you were to compress each file individually.