# Bytes from gzip file to text in python

Tags: python, file-io, gzip

Once the contents of a gzip file is extracted into a string called `text`, it looks like gibberish.  How can I turn it into something human-readable?

```
with open("zipped_ex.gz.2016") as f:
    text = f.read()
    print text
```

Note:  I'm not searching for a way to go from zipper_ex_gz.2016 to the contents.  Instead, I'm searching for a way to go from the bytestring to the contents.

Comment: This Q also pops when you search for **byte-reading particular files from a zip** - for that - you need to open the zip `my_zip = ZipFile('path/to/my.zip)`, open the file inside the zip directly `file_in_zip = my_zip.open('path/inside/zip', "r")` and `file_in_zip.read()` for read, you can also specify max number of bytes read - https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import gzip
with gzip.GzipFile("zipped_ex.gz.2016") as f:
    text = f.read()
    print text
```

On the disk, the file is a binary blop that is humanly unreadable.
To work with the data inside the archive you need to some how extract it.

In this case, in memory via the `GzipFile` module that decompresses the archive "on the fly" so when you do `f.read()` you get the archive contents, not the binary content that is the archive on your disk.

The same module can be used on a `bytes` string:

```
import io
import gzip

f = io.BytesIO(b"Your compressed gzip-file content here")
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f) as fh:
    plain_text = fh.read()
    print(plain_text)
```

**Note:** `gzip` files are in fact a single data unit compressed with the gzip format, obviously. But if you want to work with a tar file within the gzip file if you have numerous text files compressed via tar, have a look at this question: [How do I compress a folder with the Python GZip module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874837/how-do-i-compress-a-folder-with-the-python-gzip-module)

Comment: Sorry, that would work if I wanted to go from file -> contents, but I want to go from bytestring to contents.  I apologize for not making that more clear in the question.

Comment: @Someone_Else When you say from bytesstring, do you refer to bytes data recieved from, say a socket? If so, this option is still viable.

Comment: I mean from the result of calling the normal f.read() function on the file.  (I know that sounds stupid, but I'm working on something with a remote host in such a way that calling gzip.GzipFile on the original file is not an option.)

Comment: @Someone_Else, check my latest addon to the answer. There you can bass a `bytes` string into a dummy filehandle (which, gzip requires i  think) and then convert it to plaintext.